# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver (JARs are included)

Tags: java, apache, jdbc

I'm trying to start a database and create a table in it, but for some reason I keep running into the catch statement instead of loading the driver:

servlet:

```
public class dbintial {
Connection con = null;
Statement stat = null;

public String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";

public  dbintial() {
    System.out.println("intialized");

    try {

        System.out.println("intialized");

        Class.forName(driver);

        System.out.println("driver loaded");

        //get connection
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:/Users/Hady/Downloads/v5/web/hady;create=true");
        System.out.println("Connected");

        //create statement
        stat = con.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Stat created");

        //stat.executeUpdate("CREATE table user5");

        stat.executeUpdate("create table user22s34 (email varchar(25), password varchar(25), "
                + "username varchar(25), primary key(email))");

        System.out.println("Stat executed");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        //Logger.getLogger(dbintial.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("1");

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
       // Logger.getLogger(dbintial.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        System.out.println("2");
    }
        try {
            con.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

process jsp which is invoked by a button on the index html file.

```
try {
        dbintial u = new dbintial();
       u.printUsers();

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("oh god");
    }
%>
```

I've all jars installed. Running on an apache server.

Comment: Firstly, accustom yourself to start class with a capital letter. Secondly, although you say your jars are included, that driver does not seem to be loaded. More interesting than the code snippets would be your build config.

Comment: If you get a `ClassNotFoundException`, then you may **think** you have included the drivers, but they really aren't (or at least not in the place where they should be to get loaded correct, that is in `WEB-INF/lib`)

Comment: BTW: You are probably not running on Apache server. Did you mean Apache Tomcat instead?

Comment: Yeah I meant that. turns out I had the jars misplaced in the file. thank you everyone! I really do appreciate it